# Arduino ESP8266 HTTPS server DNS record verification

Tags: ssl, https, arduino, record, esp8266

I made HTTP server on my NodeMCU ESP8266 board using ESP8266WebServer library. I would like to convert it to the HTTPS server, so I used ESP8266WebServerSecure library, bought SSL certificate but I need to confirm domain verification to get certificate. To do so I need to add DNS TXT record with verification code. Could someone explain me how to do this on my server? So far I handle it by using:

```
 void verifyCertificate(){
   server.send(200, "plain/text", "verification code");

server.on("/", HTTP_GET, verifyCertificate);
```

But Im not sure if it's good way to handle domain verification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't add a DNS TXT record on the web server. To add a DNS TXT record, you need to assign a domain name to the server. This means you have to register a domain name with a registrar, create a name for the ESP8266 and set an A record for that name to be the IP address of the ESP8266. Once you have that working, you add the DNS TXT record to the ESP8266's name record as well.

The mechanism for adding records depends on your domain registrar; refer to their documentation.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I had some problems but finally I got my certificate.